# Install libconfig without being root

Tags: software-installation, libraries, non-root-user

I need to install libconfig but I do not have access to root to be able to do apt-get install, how could I install it?

PD: [github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a local installation, say in your home directory, you can use `apt-get` (or the github link) to fetch the source and configure it to build locally, usually like this (change directory as needed)

```
apt-get source libconfig
cd libconfig...
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

If you need a global installation, you'll need root or `sudo`.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is probably "you can't".

You can download the source for libconfig and, if the build tools are installed and available to you, compile it yourself.